# Conditional Concatenate inserting or not inserting underscores depending on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, concatenation

I'm a beginner on excel and I'm trying to get the following result:

```
    Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
    John   Jim    Tom    Sarah
    Ann    Betty  blank  blank
    Lee    Sue    George blank
```

What I want:

```
    John_Jim_Tom_Sarah
    Ann_Betty
    Lee_Sue_George
```

What I'm getting:

```
    John_Jim_Tom_Sarah
    Ann_Betty__
    Lee_Sue_George_
```

Do someone know how to solve it?

Comment: You should be able to use something like `IF(ISBLANK(A1,"","_"&A1))` to return the underscore only if A1 is not blank.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have? If it's a newer version, you can use `TEXTJOIN()`

Answer (score 2):

Use TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN("_",TRUE,A2:D2)
```

[image]

---

If you do not have TEXTJOIN you will need to do something like this:

```
=MID(IF(A2<>"","_"&A2,"")&IF(B2<>"","_"&B2,"")&IF(C2<>"","_"&C2,"")&IF(D2<>"","_"&D2,""),2,99)
```

[image]

Comment: [Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845229/4650297) to a UDF for TextJoin :D

Comment: @BruceWayne hey, I recognize that. :)

Comment: It worked perfectly with TEXT.JOIN

Answer (score 0):

IF you do not have the option of using `TEXTJOIN` you can use a mixture of `CONCATENATE`, `LEN` & `LEFT`:

Assuming your data starts in A2 use:

```
=LEFT(CONCATENATE(A2,"_",B2,"_",C2,"_",D2),LEN(CONCATENATE(A2,"_",B2,"_",C2,"_",D2))-(4-COUNTA(A2:D2)))
```

Its basically doing the same as `TEXTJOIN` then calculating the length of the string, and misusing off the characters to the right for each blank cell in the range, which would be the unwanted underscores.